# iOS 9 Swift 2.0 How can I get notification so when a user sends a message to another user they get notified?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications, swift2

I'm new fairly new to iOS dev but how can I get notification so when a user sends a message to another user they get notified?

Does this refer to Parse? 
Also are there any lines of codes that should be implemented?
Any advice is appreciated.

I will let you guys know if I fins a solution soon. 
Thanks!

Comment: What kind of message? SMS? iMessage?

Answer (score 1):

Parse is one of many possible solutions, it is fairly easy and convenient as you need a server to monitor for the events:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html

Here is the Parse reference:

https://parse.com/tutorials/ios-push-notifications